# How to transclude content in ui bootstrap modal directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I've made a custom directive on top of ui bootstrap modal directive so I can use the same modal template everywhere in my app.

My directive works until I try to transclude its content into the template:

http://plnkr.co/edit/YPESA3?p=preview

---

#### From index.html

```
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
  <button class="btn" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
  
  <my:modal open="shouldBeOpen" close="close()">
    <h1>Content</h1>
  </my:modal>
</div>
```

#### Module code:

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap'])

.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.open = function () {
    $scope.shouldBeOpen = true;
  };

  $scope.close = function () {
    $scope.closeMsg = 'I was closed at: ' + new Date();
    $scope.shouldBeOpen = false;
  };

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2'];

})


.directive('myModal', function() {
  return {
    restrict : 'E',
    templateUrl: 'myTpl.html',
    //transclude: true,
    scope : {
      open : '=',
      close : '&'
    }
  };
});
```

#### Modal template:

```
<div modal="open">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4>I'm a modal!</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <!--<div ng-transclude/>-->
    </div>
       
    
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-warning cancel" ng-click="close()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Uncomment transclude property from the directive and the template and you'll see you get a `TypeError: undefined is not a function.`

I can't figure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 6):

OP, your snippet is exactly what I was looking to do—thanks!

I managed to get your plunk working by passing `replace:true` as well as `transclude: true`

Here's the updated plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/gxCS2V?p=preview

I'm new to Angular, so I was interested to know why:

> replace - if set to true then the template will replace the current element, rather than append the template to the element.
>
> (via the Angular docs)

Which, of course makes sense once you know.

Good to know if you want to make your directive especially recyclable. Modals are pretty perfect example.

Related : [ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/) is worth checking out.

Answer (score 4):

Check this solution, you dont need a extra controller or angular-ui for that only pass a simple handler and use it

### example.js

```
angular.module('plunker', [], function() {

})

.directive('modal', function() {
  return {
    restrict : 'E',
    templateUrl: 'myTpl.html',
    transclude: true,
    controller: function($scope) {
      // you need get a better unique generator
      $scope.modal_id = 'modal_' + Math.floor((Math.random()*100+1));
      $scope.handler = $scope.modal_id;
    },
    scope : {
      handler : '='
    }
  };
})
.run();
```

### index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>    
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">    
  </head>
<body>

<div ng-init="handler = null">  
  <modal handler="handler">
    <h1>Content</h1>
  </modal>  
  <a href="#{{handler}}" role="button" class="btn primary" data-toggle="modal">Open me</a>
</div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js"></script>    
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### myTpl.html

```
<div id="{{modal_id}}" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="{{modal_id}}Label" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 id="{{modal_id}}Label">I'm a modal!</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div ng-transclude></div>
    </div>    
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

look how works in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7opZuK?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll have a try.
However, to be honest, , I'm more intersted to know what is wrong in my example

Comment: I decided to make a solution that does not use angular-ui by a bad experience because angular-ui gave me more problems than solutions. but will watch closely the modal directive from angular-ui